# Conditional expectation $E(XY\mid Z)$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to solve the following problem: let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 independent standard normal random variables and let be $Z=X+Y$. Calculate $E(XY\mid Z)$. I tried many approaches, but without getting the result. Any suggestion? We know previously that $Z=X+Y$ and $W=X-Y$ are independent and that $E(X\mid Z)=\frac{1}{2}Z$.

Comment: Can you not use $$\mathrm{E}(XY \vert Z ) = \mathrm{E}(X \vert Z) \cdot \mathrm{E}(Y \vert Z)?$$

Comment: This property is not valid in general. Perhaps it is for normal distributions but I'm not sure.

Comment: Express $X$, $Y$ in terms of $Z,W$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud This property is very rarely true, even for normal random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $XY=\frac{1}{4}((X+Y)^2-(X-Y)^2)$, and expectation is linear.  Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal with the same distribution, then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent.

Comment: You are welcome.